# how to check if object has some element

Tags: jquery, json

I have 2 objects received by jquery ajax -

i need to display a cross between them, meaning all the elements of object 1 and all the elements in object 2 that are not present in object one

```
$.each(user[0],function(key,value){
    var div = $("<div></div>");
    div.html("key: "+key + " value: "+value);
    div.appendTo(maindiv);
});

$.each(userLogin[0],function(key,value){
    if(user[0][key]=='undefined'){
        var div = $("<div></div>");
        div.html("key: "+key + " value: "+value);
        div.appendTo(maindiv);
    }

});
```

but since "key" here is numerical element, this logic fails
how can i check if "userLogin[0] has any keys that are present in user[0] ?

Comment: You need to iterate over the key returned. Please look for Javascript **forin**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this to see if an object has a certain property:

```
if(!user[0].hasOwnProperty(key)){
```

Your current version isn't working because you are comparing `undefined` (the constant) to `'undefined'` (the string). See this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zr7VJ/

```
var obj = {}

console.log(obj['someProp'] === 'undefined');  // false
console.log(obj['someProp'] === undefined); // true
console.log(typeof obj['someProp'] === 'undefined'); // true
```

Comment: I was wondering about that - i have many instances in my code where i compare it to undefined, and each time i got different result than expected, this clears things. thank you